# Updating all instances of a Fragment at once

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` called `LoginRowFragment` which is instantiated in several other `Fragment`s or `Activity`s. For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/loginrow"
    class="com.mydomain.myproject.LoginRowFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    

</LinearLayout>
```

As this `Fragment` is instantiated in several places, I'm trying to find a way to update the content of that `Fragment` when an action happens (in this case, when an user successfully authenticates himself), so I want all instances of that `Fragment` being updated at once, but since many of those `Fragment`s are detached at the moment of identification, I can't find out a way.

This is what I have have tried so far:

- Setting a `BroadcastReceiver` inside the `Fragment`. This doesn't fire when the `Fragment` is detached, though.
- Setting the same `id` to every instance. Bad idea, it doesn't work at all (basically I've tried this silliness because I've run out of ideas).

Is that even possible? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a constant known amount of fragments active at a time (or maybe only one, I don't know), you can store them in activity as fields and update directly when a change occures.

Then, store your current state in activity and implement a check of this state in your fragment, `onResume()` is a good place for it: `((MyActivity)getActivity()).checkState()`. Therefore, when fragments will wake up and `onResume()` gets called they'll check their state and act accordingly.

Comment: Finally this is what I implemented (or very similar), I keep track of the active `Fragment`s within an `Activity` and update the rest of them in the `onResume()` or `onAttach()`. Thanks!